# java iterative to recursive 2 nested for loop

Tags: java, recursion

I would like to check whether a string contains a sub list.
For example, `str1 = "qwertyuiop"` and `str2 = "tyu"` `returns true`.
I have written an `iterative` method.

```
public static boolean checkString(String str1, String str2) {
    for (int i=0; i<str2.length(); i++) {
        int j = 0;
        for (; j<str1.length()&& str1.charAt(j)!=str2.charAt(i); j++) {

        }
        if (j== str1.length())
            return false;
    }
    return true;    
}
```

I am trying changing it to `recursive` method but not sure how as there are two nested for loops. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do not you use str1.contains(str2) method ?

Comment: Why not just use String.contains(String seq) ?

Comment: @sam_eera @Tyler this is just an example of using nested for loop as I want to see how `recursion` will work when there's more than one loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isSubstring("ankur", "ku"));
    }

    public static boolean isSubstring(String str1, String str2) {
        if ((str1 == null) || (str2 == null) || str1.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        } else if (str1.startsWith(str2)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return isSubstring(str1.substring(1), str2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you focus on other activities. Java already includes a function to do what you are implementing, and that is [`String.contains(CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) like

```
if (str1.contains(str2)) { // <-- wherever you would have called "checkString"
  // ...
}
```